# How to spy on the original function and not the dummy in Jasmine for javascript testing?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I looked at the other questions regarding spying on functions in Jasmine but I didn't get my doubt answered there. I intend to use `andCallThrough` to track my original function in my `src` script. This is what I have:

```
describe("My Test to spy :", function() {                                       
    var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy(window, "login");                             
    beforeEach(function(){
        mySpy();
    });

    it("Expects login() will be called", function(){                               
      expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();                                         
    });    
});
```

So this test passes because its the spy that is being called right? Not the original implementation of the function. So if I use `mySpy.andCallThrough()` it gives an error. The docs are all about chaining objects and for methods. Nothing for functions. Need some help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you use `createSpy` instead of `spyOn`. `createSpy` will create a new spy so you can't use `andCallThrough` on it as there is no function to call. Using `spyOn` will replace an existing function with the spy and save the old function in the spy. So when you use `andCallThrough` it will call this old method.

You can use `createSpy` but then you have to pass a name and the original function:

```
jasmine.createSpy('someName', window.login)
```

When you use `spyOn', you have to pass the an object holding the function and the name of the function:

```
jasmine.spyOn(window, 'login')
```

Comment: Another thing, in the docs, `foo` has been initialized with something. Why is that? Without initializing I don't think I can use `spyOn`.

Comment: @Andreas Shouldn't be the last line of your example `spyOn(window, 'login')`?